# How can I make the URL into the title as a clickable link with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to be able to make the URL integrated and linked to the title.   It currently makes the title and URL separate in the picture.

```
var i;
var listItems = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('listitem');
var html = '';
for (i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
    // build the HTML for the image and name text
    console.log(listItems[i].getElementsByTagName('itemName')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue)
    html += "<div class=\"item\">" + "    <p>" + listItems[i].getElementsByTagName('itemName')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + +"<a href =" + "\"" + listItems[i].getElementsByTagName('itemURL')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "\"" + ">" + "</a>" + "</p>" + "</div>";
```

[image: This is the output, title and URL seprate]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use template literals. Code:

```js
var i;
var listItems = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('listitem');
var html = '';
for (i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
    // build the HTML for the image and name text
    console.log(listItems[i].getElementsByTagName('itemName')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue)
    html += `<div class="item"><a href = "${listItems[i].getElementsByTagName('itemURL')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue}">${listItems[i].getElementsByTagName('itemName')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue}</a></div>`;
```

Comment: With the code above I get the following output "[object HTMLCollection]" instead of the item name, do you know why this is?